# Unable to uninstall `dotnet new` via folder template?

Tags: .net-core

Is there a special method for uninstalling a folder-template `dotnet new` project beyond what is [described in the .NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates#to-uninstall-a-template-from-a-file-system-directory)?

```
dotnet new -u <FILE_SYSTEM_DIRECTORY>
```

### Steps

After setting up a folder template for `dotnet new`, I installed it ([per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates#to-install-a-template-from-a-file-system-directory)).

```
dotnet new --install ./some-template-folder/
```

This successfully puts the template in place for use with `dotnet new {shortName}`.

```
The template "Some Template Name" was created successfully.
```

Unfortunately, I cannot uninstall that template afterwards using the appropriate command ([per docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates#to-uninstall-a-template-from-a-file-system-directory))

```
dotnet new --uninstall ./some-template-folder/
```

Resulting in the following output instead.

```
Could not find something to uninstall called '.\some-template-folder\'.
```

### Details

If it helps, here is the folder's minimal **template.json** file contained in the folder's **.template.config** sub-folder.

```js
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Some Author",
    "classifications": [ "Some", "Various", "Search Keywords" ],
    "identity": "Some.Identity",
    "shortName": "name-used-in-dotnetnew",
    "name": "Some Template Name"
}
```

### Filed bug

[dotnet/templating#1226](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1226)

Comment: Just a note that in newer `dotnet` versions, the uninstall command is used without the hyphens (`dotnet new uninstall` instead of the older `dotnet new --uninstall`). The accepted answer below has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the state of the templates specific to my machine. After doing a `dotnet new --debug:reinit` to revert the templates to their freshly installed state, the issue went away.

### Potential issues

While my issue was machine-specific, there were some elements unique to path uninstalls via `dotnet new uninstall <path>` that could also cause this issue.

Note: Older `dotnet` installs used `dotnet new --uninstall` while newer installs use `dotnet new uninstall` (without the `--` parameter). This answer has been updated to use the newer syntax.

#### Make paths absolute

While you can install from a relative path (e.g., `dotnet new install ./some-template`), you must uninstall from a fully qualified path.

```
dotnet new uninstall C:\full\path\to\some-template
```

#### Avoid terminal slash

Additionally, when you do pass in a fully qualified path to `uninstall`, do not include the terminal slash that your command-line environment may auto-include when you tab complete the path.

```
dotnet new uninstall C:\full\path\to\some-template #<-- no terminal \ here
```

### [Edit: new uninstall list option]

While all of the below details are still currently accurate, they have now added a system for determining exactly what uninstall string is required. Run the uninstall command without any parameters to see a list of installed templates listed by the exact string required to uninstall them.

```
dotnet new uninstall
```

And it will output a list like this, with short names for NuGet packages and full paths for locally installed templates.

```
Template Instantiation Commands for .NET Core CLI

Currently installed items:
 Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ItemTemplates
 ...
 dotnet-new-project-helper
 C:\full\path\to\some-template
```

You could then uninstall that final template with the listed path.

```
dotnet new uninstall C:\full\path\to\some-template
```

Comment: I've been scratching my head over this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template  indicates that you can uninstall. With `dotnet new --uninstall .\`  is that guide, in fact, wrong?